# Excel VBA Erro 1004 ao salvar arquivo

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba, macro

Boa tarde, estou tentando criar um backup automático ao abrir uma planilha do excel, porém ocorre um erro dizendo que não foi possível encontrar o arquivo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu ocultei algumas partes do caminho por questões de privacidade, segue o código abaixo:

```
Sub Autobackup()
'
' Autobackup Macro
'

'
    Dim path As String, name As String, data As String, ext As String
    path = "https://site.sharepoint.com/sites/Gestao/Documentos Compartilhados/General/BACKUP Banco de Dados/"
    name = " Banco de Dados de Contratos"
    data = Format(Date, "ww.yyyy")
    ext = ".xlsm"

     ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Filename:= _
        path & "Backup Semana " & data & name & ext

End Sub
```

O estranho é que esse erro só ocorre quando eu uso o método "SaveCopyAs".Quando eu uso o método "SaveAs", o Excel consegue achar o caminho e salvar o arquivo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas eu não quero salvar a planilha em outro local, apenas fazer uma cópia dela.

Notem que o código abaixo, é exatamente igual ao de cima, o que muda apenas são os métodos do objeto "ActiveWorkbook"

```
Sub Autobackup()
'
' Autobackup Macro
'

'
    Dim path As String, name As String, data As String, ext As String
    path = "https://site.sharepoint.com/sites/Gestao/Documentos Compartilhados/General/BACKUP Banco de Dados/"
    name = " Banco de Dados de Contratos"
    data = Format(Date, "ww.yyyy")
    ext = ".xlsm"

     ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        path & "Backup Semana " & data & name & ext

End Sub
```

Ou seja, o caminho está certo, mas por algum motivo, o Excel não consegue salvar uma cópia.
Alguém sabe me explicar o porquê?

Answer (score -1):

tudo bom? Já tive este problema. Este erro acontece quando o VBA "não acha" qual Planilha é a certa. Tente substituir de ActiveWorkbook por ThisWorkbook que irá resolver!